# Table Directives for Row and Cell

Tags: python-sphinx, directive, restructuredtext, myst

I was wondering if it is possible to compose a table with just directives.

Currently I use:

`````
    ````{list-table}
    
    * - My text in the left cell
    
      - ```{figure} ./image.png
        ---
        name: image
        ---
        Firgure in right cell
        ```
    
    ````
`````

What I want to achieve is to do this table without symbols and indents, but just directives. Something that I imagine could look like this:

```````
    ``````{list-table}
    
    `````{list-table-row}
    ````{list-table-cell}
    
    My text in the left cell
      
    ````
    ````{list-table-cell}
    
    ```{figure} ./image.png
    ---
    name: image
    ---
    Firgure in right cell
    ```
    
    ````
    `````
    
    ``````
```````

I was unable to find any information online, if such directives for table elements (row & cell) exist. It also does not have to be a `list-table`.